# How to show a QLabel in fullscreen?

Tags: c++, qt, fullscreen, qlabel

I have a `ui` with a `QPushButton` and a `QLabel`. I would like the `QLabel` to be displayed in full screen on my laptop whenever I push that button.

I tried the following code:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_fullScreenBtn_clicked()
{
    // ui->myImage is a QLabel*
    ui->myImage->setText("going full screen");
    ui->myImage->showMaximized();
    ui->myImage->QWidget::showFullScreen(); 
}
```

I can see this function is executed, but it doesn't display my label in full screen. What am I doing incorrectly/missing?

I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1 and made my GUI using the built-in graphical interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `QLabel` is part of another widget and therefore displayed as a child widget instead due to the default [`Qt::Widget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) flag:

> This is the default type for `QWidget`. 
>   Widgets of this type are child widgets if they have a parent, and
>   independent windows if they have no parent. See also `Qt::Window` and `Qt::SubWindow.`

Therefore, the solution is to change the flag to `Qt::Window` manually as follows:

```
ui->myImage->setWindowFlag(Qt::Window);
```

Pre Qt 5.9 users can use the following:

```
ui->myImage->setWindowFlags(ui->myImage->windowFlags() | Qt::Window);
```

Note that you should call `showFullScreen` after you changed the window flags as [documented by Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop):

> **Note**: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a
>   window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make
>   the widget visible again..

**Undo maximisation**

The window flag should be removed to undo the maximisation. This can be done as follows:

```
ui->myImage->setWindowFlag(Qt::Window, false);
ui->myImage->show();
```

Pre Qt 5.9 users can use the following:

```
ui->myImage->setWindowFlags(ui->myImage->windowFlags() & ~Qt::Window);
ui->myImage->show();
```

Note that the call to `show` is needed as pointed out above.

Answer (score 1):

The showMaximized and showFullScreens work on a QWidget that **dont** have a parent (that are actual windows, not contained widgets). so you have a few different options there on your code.

1 - Create a QStackedLayout or QStackedWidget with **only** your QLabel, and when you trigger your slot, do this:

```
void MainWindow::on_fullScreenBtn_clicked()
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex( indexOfTheLabel);
}
```

this will make the Label take the whole screen.

2 - You can also remove the parent of the QLabel, but this will generate a complicated mess, so, don't.

```
void MainWindow::on_fullScreenBtn_clicked()
{
    ui->myImage->setParent(nullptr);
    ui->myImage->setText("going full screen");
    ui->myImage->showMaximized();
    ui->myImage->showFullScreen(); 
}
```

Don't do this second one.

Comment: Please mention why one should not use the last method: Setting the parent to `nullptr` will (probably) result in a memory leakage, because you change the object ownership tree as an undesired side effect.

Comment: also it breaks the layout and you have to manually re-insert it on the layout later.

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling the show() method on your MainWindow instance, in your main function? Something like that:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;

    window.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Yes I do call the show() function. But I want this label to fill my entire screen only after having pushed a pushbutton. My guess is that the code you posted here doesn't take that into consideration.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted what you wrote. I understood that your label was not displayed at all. My mistake