# QLabel full screen: make use of existing shortcuts (without new code)

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget to navigate through a bunch of images. I show the image in a `QLabel`, and have a bunch of functions, with each its own shortcut, to edit the image or to navigate.

Now I would like to create an option to show the image (the `QLabel`) in full screen mode, but **I still want to use the defined shortcuts, and call the functions to which they are assigned** (such that I can still navigate through the images without having to leave the full screen mode).

Currently I'm close, but I cannot use any of the shortcuts (so I cannot even exit the full screen mode). 
I show the `QLabel` full screen using:

```
ui->myImage->setWindowFlags(ui-> myImage->windowFlags() | Qt::Window);
ui->myImage->showFullScreen();
ui->myImage->showMaximized();
```

(Taken from: [Qt - How to show a QLabel in fullscreen on my laptop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385978/qt-how-to-show-a-qlabel-in-fullscreen-on-my-laptop))

*I wish to avoid asigning these shortcuts more then once in different ways. More specifically I really want to minimize the code to do this, to keep my code readable, flexible, and maintainable. I.e. no separate widgets or classes.*

> **Edit**
>
> Tried so far:
>
> - Adding an action and connecting it to the relevant function, e.g.
>
>   ```
>     connect(ui->actionMinimize,SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),this,SLOT(on_minimize_clicked()));
>   ```
> - Adding the following attribute:
>
>   ```
>     ui-> myImage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
>   ```

Comment: Have you tried to set a [`Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute to your label?

Comment: @thuga Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not help. I've tried this: `ui-> myImage->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: How about setting the context of your shortcut to [`Qt::ApplicationShortcut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum)?

Comment: @thuga That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, the details of @thuga's answer. I've put the following in my `MainWindow`'s constructor:

```
QShortcut *shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Escape), this);

shortcut->setContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);

connect(shortcut , SIGNAL( activated() ), this, SLOT( stopFullScreen() ) );
```